# Can relative pronoun be omitted in the following sentence?

Tags: relative-pronouns

> The color of house that I built is red.

This sentence can be written in following way.

> The color of house I built is red.

I can omit *that*, because *that* is indicating the house, and it is the object of the verb *built*. A relative pronoun can be omitted if it indicates the object. But if it indicates the subject, it can not be omitted. Am I right?

Let's see the following sentence.

> Apparel engineers are responsible for establishing and monitoring processes essential to maintain product consistency on time production and fair treatment of workers.

In this sentence, I think *that* has been omitted before *essential*. I can write this sentence in the following way.

> Apparel engineers are responsible for establishing and monitoring processes *that  are* essential to maintain product consistency on time production and fair treatment of workers.

Is it correct? Here *that* has been used to indicate to *processes*. In *that are essential to maintain ...* the relative pronoun *that* is a subject, not object. Please tell me why *that* has been omitted before the word *essential*? Please give proper explanation with some effective examples.

Comment: The problem is that the first noun phrase in both sentences is already ungrammatical -- _house_ should have a definite article. And the title is also ungrammatical. As for deleting _that_, any relative pronoun may be deleted, optionally, when it is not the subject of the relative clause it introduces. Since the subject is _I_, _that_ may be deleted, and so may _which_. Indeed, if it's deleted, it's not clear whether it was sposta be _which_ or _that_ -- another speaker's choice foreclosed by deletion.

Comment: @John: I can see that omitting the article in OP's first example creates a "questionable" utterance. But I can't easily see why I don't like that one, whereas *The type of car I bought is diesel* seems fine (and would seem decidedly weird if it *did* include the article).

Comment: That's because _type_ is not the same kind of noun as _color_. That's why naming "parts of speech" is pointless -- not all adjectives (or nouns, or verbs) follow the same rules as others. Pretty much, every lexical item  has its own history and idioms and habits and affordances. There are practically no useful grammatical rules that depend on "Noun" or "Adjective" alone. Color nominals and classificational nominals are a good example of  this.

Comment: @JohnLawler Are you therefore saying *The colour of car I like best is red*, is not grammatical/idiomatic?

Comment: @JohnLawler Erm, that's a bit of a mild overstatement, I do believe :) and it's really a dangerous thing to say to @Fumblefingers! Mr Fingers believes that when you use a noun as temporal adjunct it turns into an adverb! ;)

Comment: @WS2: Yes, I'm saying that about that sentence. _Type of_ **can** take a generic object NP without any article in normal sentences, while _color of_ **can't**. English articles are very tricky, and usually are one of the last things non-native speakers learn to control. So it's important to correct learners when they're used incorrectly.

Comment: ... There are many examples of 'the colour of car' on the internet, and I'm quite familiar with the usage. eg _Do you know that the colour of car you drive can reveal a great deal about your personality?_ This doesn't jar with me at all. Perhaps it's become more accepted in the UK than in the US.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yes, I must agree with Edwin. If it is wrong or non-idiomatic then I have been making the error all my life. *The colour of car I prefer, never seems to be available in the nearly-new market*.

Comment: In _color of car_, _car_ is being used to refer to the general category or concept of cars, so no article is used. In _color of the car_, it's referring to a specific car, so we use an article.

Comment: @JohnLawler, Edwin, WS2, Barmar I think the problem with the OP's example is that he's not referring to a quality of cars in general but a colour of a specific car: *the car that I built*. I think if the sentence read *"The colour of house that we build depends on the surrounding environment*", then that particular  problem will disappear.

Comment: I don't see why we need to bother with those details of article shading; they're lost on the OP.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct.  The phrases presented are *relative clauses*.  Typical relative clauses are introduced with a relative pronoun (who, that, etc.), but this is not necessary.  A relative clause that excludes the pronoun has an *elliptical relative pronoun*.

> The flavor I love is vanilla.

The elliptical relative pronoun is "that" to create this sentence:

> The flavor that I love is vanilla.

In your longer example, you are correct in noticing that the adjective clause describing the type of processes possesses an elliptical relative pronoun.